# Is & faster than % when checking for odd numbers?

Tags: python, performance, bit-manipulation, modulo

To check for odd and even integer, is the lowest bit checking more efficient than using the modulo?

```
>>> def isodd(num):
        return num & 1 and True or False

>>> isodd(10)
False
>>> isodd(9)
True
```

Comment: What's with "and True or False"?

Comment: If you're trying to get a boolean result, just do bool(num & 1)

Comment: "0 is true and 1 is false"?! Now THAT would be an INTERESTING language to program in, indeed...!!!

Comment: I screwed that up. In Python, 0 IS FALSE and 1 IS TRUE. (But in *nix, exit codes of 0 indicate success. bash is indeed interesting.)

Comment: Yep, I remember ending a program once (on an IBM Instruments minicomputer for lab control) with "return 0" and getting 16 scary error messages on the printing console (turns out the return code was interpreted bit by bit to mean 1=success, 0=failure, for each of 16 possible classes of system errors;-) -- that's why ANSI C specified EXIT_SUCCESS instead of that 0, I believe (though I think nobody uses it;-).

Comment: @Selinap: why tag this as python3.1? AFAIK all of the issues canvassed are version-independent all the way back to when True/False were introduced (2.2?).

Comment: If this is actually something you care about, Python is not the language for you.

Comment: @JanMatula Considering how much the OP might care about this is irrelevant: questions are not less valid if those who ask them aren't too worried about their aspects. Also, programmers often find themselves forced to use a specific language, and may want/need to know about these aspects, even if they are aware about other and more important drawbacks of those languages; but, most importantly, they may need to know all that *especially* if they are aware about those drawbacks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yep. The `timeit` module in the standard library is how you check on those things.  E.g:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'def isodd(x): x & 1' 'isodd(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.446 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'def isodd(x): x & 1' 'isodd(10)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.443 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'def isodd(x): x % 2' 'isodd(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.461 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'def isodd(x): x % 2' 'isodd(10)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.453 usec per loop
```

As you see, on my (first-day==old==slow;-) Macbook Air, the `&` solution is repeatably between 7 and 18 nanoseconds faster than the `%` solution.

`timeit` not only tells you what's faster, but by how much (just run the tests a few times), which usually shows how supremely UNimportant it is (do you *really* care about 10 nanoseconds' difference, when the overhead of calling the function is around 400?!-)...

Convincing programmers that micro-optimizations are essentially irrelevant has proven to be an impossible task -- even though it's been 35 years (over which computers have gotten orders of magnitude faster!) since Knuth [wrote](http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf)

> We should forget about small
> efficiencies, say about 97% of the
> time: premature optimization is the
> root of all evil.

which as he explained is a quote from an even older statement from Hoare. I guess everybody's totally convinced that THEIR case falls in the remaining 3%!

So instead of endlessly repeating "it doesn't matter", we (Tim Peters in particular deserves the honors there) put in the standard Python library module `timeit`, that makes it trivially easy to measure such micro-benchmarks and thereby lets at least *some* programmers convince themselves that, hmmm, this case DOES fall in the 97% group!-)

Comment: The compiler isn't going to optimize those to the same instruction(s)? Excuse my Python-ignorance if it shows.

Comment: No, the Python compiler is itself optimized to be maximally simple, reliable, and fast -- it doesn't do optimizations such as changing the operation in use (for which it would have to infer that `x` is always integer, for example). Try psyco if you need this kind of low-level optimization (i.e. if every nanosecond matters).

Comment: Thank you for adding a point about the unimportance of such a small difference. Even performing the calculation hundreds, or even thousands of times, this is probably one of the worst "optimizations" you can make - not only does it hurt readability (IMO), but you don't get that much back out of it. I never want to pay more than what I get.

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot Python isn't statically typed. (right?) There goes the Python ignorance alarm again.

Comment: @Thomas, I actually edited the answer repeatedly to explain exactly how irrelevant it is, provide Knuth's quote, explain why we put timeit in the library, &c; but SO is very much of a 100-yards dash, so to get any rep about it I chose to provide the solution first, the homilies later. Looks like this time your choice to provide only the homilies, with no code or solution, is winning the rep race;-). (BTW, I don't think either &1 or %2 is any less readable than the other, in this case).

Comment: Alex: +1. You did a fine job providing the facts. However, in this case, I just felt that the idea of premature optimization over something so minuscule is the worst thing a developer can do.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, but if just preaching it by the likes of Hoare and Knuth still hasn't gotten to people in 35/40 years, what chances have you or I to get through by just preaching?-) timeit in my experience is more effective because it lets people _see for themselves_!-)

Comment: And I learned something new. I'll probably abuse the hell out of timeit when I'm doing stuff in Python over the next few weeks. But, IMO, every voice helps. And now, when someone else reads this, they'll see (1) which one really is faster and then (2) reasons why they shouldn't care. Which was my goal.

Comment: @Gman, it's *DEFINITELY* the case that Python isn't statically typed (its typing is strong but dynamic); psyco, unladen swallow, etc, do or plan to do type inference or specialization JIT to get the speed back when feasible (like Javascript V8 and other JS engines, etc).

Comment: @Thomas, absolutely right, and if you see strange effects with timeit be sure to post SO questions (it's much harder to use on stuff that's not idempotent, e.g. timing `alist.append(something)`...!-)

Comment: Assuming that any given optimization is premature is flawed

Comment: I wouldn't divide numbers to check if they are even when doing math on paper, so why would I do so when programming? All you really care for is the last bit of the given int, if it's 1 it's odd. Things like this tend to bite at scale, when dealing with large sets of large numbers.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I learned so much from your answer.

Answer (score 26):

To be totally honest, **I don't think it matters.**

The first issue is readability. What makes more sense to other developers? I, personally, would expect a modulo when checking the evenness/oddness of a number. I would expect that most other developers would expect the same thing. By introducing a different, and unexpected, method, you might make code reading, and therefore maintenance, more difficult.

The second is just a fact that you probably won't ever have a bottleneck when doing either operation. I'm for optimization, but early optimization is the worst thing you can do in any language or environment. If, for some reason, determining if a number is even or odd is a bottleneck, then find the fastest way of solving the problem. However, this brings me back to my first point - the first time you write a routine, it should be written in the most readable way possible.

Comment: I'm half expecting down-votes on this, but I think this is an important point for anyone who is wondering this (or any similar) question, so it's going to stay.

Comment: Not a down vote persay...  But, it has been the Pythonic solution in cases like this to profile the "obvious" options and prefer the fastest.

Comment: semiuseless: I'm still learning Python, but I personally think that the modulo operator would be more Pythonic simply because you are doing what is expected. It's, to me at least, far more obvious and clear.

Comment: I'm with you on that. As Donald Knuth said, "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @gutofb7: I gave the complete quote _and_ the link to the PDF of Knuth's great article (also the first article proposing indentation as the sole mean of indicating blocks, I believe) in my answer about 8 minutes before your comment;-). BTW, in this case I believe %2 and &1 are of exactly-equivalent readability (anybody who doesn't understand bitwise-and will have trouble understanding a '%' that has absolutely nothing to do with percentages, etc etc;-).

Comment: "What makes more sense to other developers?"  I'd say `is_even()` makes more sense than both.

Answer (score 11):

The best optimization you can get is to *not* put the test into a function. '`number % 2`' and 'number & 1' are very common ways of checking odd/evenness, experienced programmers will recognize the pattern instantly, and you can always throw in a comment such as '# if number is odd, then blah blah blah' if you really need it to be obvious.

```
# state whether number is odd or even
if number & 1:
    print "Your number is odd"
else:
    print "Your number is even"
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does `%` and `&` do in python?

Comment: how this number & 1 gives odd number?

Answer (score 4):

"return num & 1 and True or False" ? Wah! If you're speed-crazy (1) "return num & 1" (2) inline it: `if somenumber % 2 == 1` is legible AND beats `isodd(somenumber)` because it avoids the Python function call.

Comment: Yep, avoiding the function call is a big win (though the ==1 is really redundant) -- avoiding the call cuts about 300 nanoseconds from the 450 or so I measured in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

John brings up a good point. The real overhead is in the function call:

```
me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'9 % 2'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0271 usec per loop
me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'10 % 2'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0271 usec per loop

me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'9 & 1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0271 usec per loop
me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'9 & 1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0271 usec per loop

me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'def isodd(x): x % 2' 'isodd(10)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.334 usec per loop
me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'def isodd(x): x % 2' 'isodd(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.358 usec per loop

me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'def isodd(x): x & 1' 'isodd(10)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.317 usec per loop
me@localhost ~> python -mtimeit -s'def isodd(x): x & 1' 'isodd(9)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.319 usec per loop
```

Interestingly both methods remore the same time without the function call.

Comment: What if I use lambda to replace the function?

isodd = lambda num: num & 1 and True or False

Comment: Your non-function tests measure *empty code*, since you put the expressions into the *setup*.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python 3.6 the answer is **no**. Using the code bellow on a 2017 MBP shows that using modulo is faster.

```
# odd.py
from datetime import datetime

iterations = 100_000_000


def is_even_modulo(n):
    return not n % 2


def is_even_and(n):
    return not n & 1


def time(fn):
    start = datetime.now()
    for i in range(iterations, iterations * 2):
        fn(i)
    print(f'{fn.__name__}:', datetime.now() - start)


time(is_even_modulo)
time(is_even_and)
```

Gives this result:

```
$ python3 -m odd
is_even_modulo: 0:00:14.347631
is_even_and: 0:00:17.476522
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1
```

As suggested in other answers, the function calls is a large overhead, however, removing it shows that modulo is still faster than bitwise and in Python 3.6.1:

```
# odd.py
from datetime import datetime

iterations = 100_000_000


def time_and():
    start = datetime.now()
    for i in range(iterations):
        i & 1 
    print('&:', datetime.now() - start)


def time_modulo():
    start = datetime.now()
    for i in range(iterations):
        i % 2
    print('%:', datetime.now() - start)


time_modulo()
time_and()
```

Results:

```
$ python3 -m odd
%: 0:00:05.134051
&: 0:00:07.250571
```

Bonus: it turns out this takes about double the time to run in Python 2.7.

```
$ time python2 -m odd
('&:', '0:00:20.169402')
('%:', '0:00:19.837755')

real    0m41.198s
user    0m39.091s
sys 0m1.899s
$ time python3 -m odd
&: 0:00:11.375059
%: 0:00:08.010738

real    0m19.452s
user    0m19.354s
sys 0m0.042s
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the evil optimization, it takes away the very idiomatic "var % 2 == 0" that every coder understands without looking twice. So this is violates pythons zen as well for very little gain.

Furthermore a = b and True or False has been superseded for better readability by

return True if num & 1 else False

Answer (score 0):

Was really surprised none of the above answers did both variable setup (timing literal is different story) and no function invocation (which obviously hides "lower terms"). Stuck on that timing from ipython's timeit, where I got clear winner x&1 - better for ~18% using python2.6 (~12% using python3.1).

On my very old machine:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'x = 777' 'x&1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.18 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'x = 777' 'x%2'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.219 usec per loop

$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'x = 777' 'x&1'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.282 usec per loop
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'x = 777' 'x%2'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.323 usec per loop
```