# Preferred method of checking for even number

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, bit-manipulation

I know that there are already questions about how to check if something is even.

I want to know what the official preference (if there is one) as well as the best performing way of checking even/odd is where

- It evaluates to `True` if the number is even
- It evaluates to `False` if the number is odd

### The methods I know of are

- `number % 2 == 0`
- `not number % 2`
- `not number & 1`

### My questions

- What is the officially preferred way of doing this? (If applicable)
- What is the effiecent way of doing this? (Performance wise)

Comment: Please explain your downvote so I can improve.

Comment: good question indeed, i never thought in that way. learned a new piece of information today because of your question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**More easily understable way** (therefore more pythonic)

```
 number % 2 == 0
```

**Slightly more optimal way**

```
not number & 1
```

They have almost similiar computational cost so I recommend `%`.

For more details about the performance look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089936/is-faster-than-when-checking-for-odd-numbers).

Comment: I'm just asking about for a given int `number` not for a list of numbers. Are you saying the preferred way is `number % 2 == 0`?

Comment: Python isn't compiled so those optimization arguments don't really apply.

Comment: Used list just as an example. It really doesn't matter but i prefer `number % 2 == 0` because it is easily understandable and its my opinion. I have added a SO post's answer which you may consider to look at.

Comment: My comment about optimization was in response to the linked answer.

Comment: @timotree i know python doesn't compile a code. I have updated my answer with a new linked answer, have a look at that.

Comment: I didn't notice that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129755/discussion-between-timotree-and-wasi-ahmad).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen all of those, so it is debatable which is best. If you are going for clarity, probably `number % 2 == 0` is the closest match between the code and the purpose. This clearly finds the remainder when divided by 2. Others may disagree, so this question has no clear answer.

The fastest method is `not (number & 1)`. Using `%timeit` in iPython on something like

```
%timeit for number in range(1000): number % 2 == 0
```

gives me:

```
number % 2 == 0: 149 µs per loop
not number % 2: 130 µs per loop
not (number % 2): 132 µs per loop
not number & 1: 106 µs per loop
not (number & 1): 107 µs per loop
```

Despite that data, I ran similar and more involved tests in a project of mine and the last usually was quicker than the next-to-last. Note that the parentheses do affect the speed somewhat, due to order of operations.

Comment: Is there an official standard "preferred" or "pythonic" way?

Comment: As I wrote, I have seen all of these techniques in actual use and wondered the same thing myself. All my evidence says there is not any agreed-on preferred way.