# Is this function to determine if a number is even or odd valid to use in real code?

Tags: python

This question came up as I was trying to find a way to determine if a number is even or odd using bit shifts, then as I got to an answer, I wanted to know if this solution is worth using in any case.

Here's my code, and you can see my function isEven() to determine if a number is even or odd on it.

```
from random import randint

myList = list()
even = list()
odd = list()

def isEven(number):
    halfN = number >> 1
    if number == halfN << 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(20):
    myList.append(randint(1, 100))

for each in myList:
    if isEven(each):
        even.append(each)
    else:
        odd.append(each)
    
print(f"Lista inicial de aleatórios contendo {len(myList)} elementos: {myList}")
print(f"Lista de pares contendo {len(even)} elementos: {even}")
print(f"Lista de ímpares contendo {len(odd)} elementos: {odd}")
```

Comment: It will work, but it's a silly way to do it.

Comment: Don't write `if thing: return True; else: return False`, write `return thing` (or `return bool(thing)` in cases where it's not already a boolean but for some reason must be made one).

Comment: If I were going to use this technique, I'd just write `return number == (number >> 1) << 1`. But it's much simpler to test the low-order bit directly rather than detecting if a right shift restores it: `return not (number & 1)`.

Comment: Seems reasonable (other than you might think about `return number == halfN << 1`). I think there are clearer implementations even using bit shift though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089936/is-faster-than-when-checking-for-odd-numbers

Comment: (Though at least on my machine, the straightforward `return n % 2 == 0` is about 2x faster than the bitwise `&`, and 7x faster than the dual bit shift operations. Python `int` values are not just raw machine words, so bit operations aren't more efficient than any other operation.)

Comment: @JonSG I'm curious about bit shift solutions, but there aren't any on that page. Did you post the wrong link?

Comment: @chepner Speed depends on the size, `& 1` is constant time, `% 2` is not. Granted, with their use case of testing list lengths that's irrelevant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's valid.

```
halfN = number >> 1
```

shifts the number to the right one bit, which discards the low-order bit.

```
if number == halfN << 1:
```

This shifts `halfN` to the left 1 bit, which will fill in the low-order bit with `0`. If this is equal to `number`, it means that the original number had `0` as the low-order bit, which means it's even.

I wouldn't use it in any real application, though. The simplest (and very efficient) way to test whether a number is even is with modulus:

```
def isEven(number: int) -> boolean:
    return number % 2 == 0
```