# pyQt5 row lines not extending under cells with style delegates

Tags: python, pyqt5

With the code supplied, it has merged cells and cells with background colours (it's a bit lengthy and modified to a working sample for testing purposes), the row line (which is placed under every second row) won't appear under any cell that has a style delegate attached to it.  Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem, QStyledItemDelegate, QSizePolicy, QStyle)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import random
import sys

class BottomLineDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        # Draw line only on even rows
        if (index.row() + 1) % 2 == 0:
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter.drawLine(
                option.rect.bottomLeft(),
                option.rect.bottomRight(),
            )
        value = index.data()
        if index.column() in (7, 8, 9) and value:
            color = Qt.blue  # Change the color as desired
            text_color = Qt.white  # Set the text color to white
            painter.fillRect(option.rect.adjusted(10, 10, -10, -10), color)
            painter.setPen(text_color)
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignCenter, index.data())
            painter.setPen(text_color)
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignCenter, index.data())
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        columns_blue_bg = [7, 8, 9]
        value = index.data()
        if value is None:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor(Qt.transparent)
        elif index.column() in columns_blue_bg:
            if value:
                option.displayAlignment = (Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        option.state &= ~(QStyle.State_Selected | QStyle.State_MouseOver | QStyle.State_HasFocus)

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.initUI()
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(
            BottomLineDelegate(self.tableWidget))

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget - Repeating Merged Cells")
        self.resize(660, 300)
        conLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        required_rows = len(self.data) * 2
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(required_rows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(15)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        # Hide headers
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        # Adjust widths of specific columns
        column_width = 70  # Set the desired width
        for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(col, column_width)
        # Set initial merged cells and data
        self.insert_data_into_table(self.data)
        # Set additional properties for the table
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # Connect cellClicked signal to fetch and print cell value
        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.on_cell_clicked)
        self.setLayout(conLayout)

    def on_cell_clicked(self, row, col):
        # Fetch the item from the clicked cell using the stored instance variable
        item = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
        if item is not None:
            # Get the text from the item and print only the top line (if it's a multi-line text)
            text = item.text().split('\n')[0]
            print(f"Clicked Cell Value: {text}")
            # Retrieve and print the value from the first column
            first_column_item = self.tableWidget.item(row+1, 0)
            if first_column_item is not None:
                first_column_text = first_column_item.text()
                print(f"First Column Value: {first_column_text}")

    def insert_data_into_table(self, new_data):
        print(new_data)
        self.data = new_data
        data_offset = 0
        required_rows = len(self.data) * 2  # Assuming each block consists of 4 rows
        total_rows = required_rows
        # Get the current row count of the table
        current_rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(total_rows)
        for i in range(0, required_rows, 2):
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 2, 1, 2)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 4, 1, 2)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 7, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 8, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 9, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 10, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 11, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 12, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 14, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 2, QTableWidgetItem(self.data[data_offset][0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.data[data_offset][1])))
            try:
                value = str(self.data[data_offset][2])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 4, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(self.data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 5, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][4][0]}\n{self.data[data_offset][5][0]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 9, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][4][1]}\n{self.data[data_offset][5][1]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 8, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][4][2]}\n{self.data[data_offset][5][2]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 7, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][6][0]}\n{self.data[data_offset][7][0]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 10, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][6][1]}\n{self.data[data_offset][7][1]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 11, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = f"{self.data[data_offset][6][2]}\n{self.data[data_offset][7][2]}"
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 0, 12, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            data_offset += 1

def generate_random_data():
    random_data = []
    for _ in range(10):  # Generating 10 rows of random data
        row_data = [
            f"Name_{random.randint(100, 999)}",
            random.randint(1000, 9999),
            random.randint(0, 100),
            [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)],
            [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)],
            [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)],
            [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)]
        ]
        random_data.append(row_data)
    return random_data

def run_app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle("Test Table")
    window.resize(800, 600)
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    window.setLayout(layout)
    random_table_data = generate_random_data()
    table = Table(data=random_table_data)
    layout.addWidget(table)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_app()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using spans, the index of the cell is the *starting* row or column of the cell, not the final one.

In order to always draw the bottom line of cell spanning multiple rows, the correct approach is to check the [`rowSpan()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#rowSpan) of the table, using the index coordinates.

```py
        if (
            index.row() % 2 
            or option.widget.rowSpan(index.row(), index.column()) > 1
        ):
            # draw bottom line
```

<sup>Note that I changed the original row comparison, as it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a further operation (`+ 1`) for parity checking; doing `row % 2` is simpler and quite more readable, as it instantly tells you if are getting an even row (even if may be a bit unintuitive after further thoughts, since the row number is actually odd).

An alternative is to use the `&` operator, which does a simple bitwise **AND** operation checking which bits of the row number are in common with `1` (`index.row() & 1`): even integers always have `0` as their last bit (2 is `10`, 4 is `100`, etc.), while odd ones always have `1` (3 is `11`, 5 is `101`, etc.).

Both the above solutions will offer a negligible improvement in performance (with the bitwise slightly faster in certain cases), but they would certainly be better for readability at least for this scenario. Further reading: [Is & faster than % when checking for odd numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089936).</sup>